# Linq to Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, ignite-ui, iggrid

I am new to javascript and having problems getting my head around a problem, that I am having. I have a list that I am trying to pass into a javascript file containing a datagrid called Grid.js.

How do I put a `C#` `List` into the correct format for javascript? Also how do I pass the js array from model to script?

controller:

```
Products = (from product context.Products
           select new project.Models.ProductsList
           {
               ProductID = Product.Id,
               Name = customer.Name,
               ProductNumber = customer.ProductNumber,
           }).ToList();
```

Format of DataSource for Grid(javascript).

```
var products= [{ "ProductID": 1, "Name": "Car", "ProductNumber": "AR-5381"},];
```

view

```
<table id="grid"></table><br />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../GridScript/ProductGrid.js">
    $(document).ready(myFunction());
</script>
```

Grid.js

```
var products = [];

$(myFunction() {
    $("#grid").igGrid({

        autoGenerateColumns: true,
        width: "80%",
        height: "600px",
        showHeaders: true,
        fixedHeaders: true,
        defaultColumnWidth: "200px",

        columns: [
            { headerText: "ProductID", key: "ProductID", dataType: "number" },
            { headerText: "Name", key: "Name", dataType: "string" },
            { headerText: "ProductNumber", key: "ProductNumber", dataType: "string" },
        ],

        dataSource: products,

        features: [
            {
                name: 'Paging',
                type: "local",
                pageSize: 25
            }
        ]
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you include the declaration for `myFunction`?

Comment: `String myJSON = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Products)` will give you the object serialized as JSON. You may need to **nuget** the NewtonSoft library but trust me it's worth it. You'll still need to add the `var products = ...` to the client-side script, but that's just a detail. If you Google `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` you'll see plenty of references, though the first few I checked weren't terribly readable.

Comment: Your question is common, how does one send LINQ enumerable to browser?  The answer as posted is that you have to use JSON.  I see you are using Jquery Igrid, I have no experience with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what your asking but I think you are looking for the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class

Something Like:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(Products);
```

See The link for more details.

Comment: Thanks for that How would I then pass from the view to the Java script

Comment: myFunction(products) in grid.js and $(document).ready(myFunction(products)); when calling it.